# set upstream branch tracking after moving and re-adding remote URL in simple-git

Tags: node.js, git, npm, git-branch

The following piece of code checks if the local repository exist, and sync the changes from remote repository using [simple-git](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-git). I was having some issues with `JWT` token expiring after 24 hours, this was fixed by removing and re-adding the remote repository URL.

```
if (fs.existsSync(cachePath)) {
      debug(`Local Path ${cachePath} Exists`);
      // debug('Checking `git status` on local repo');
      // Fetch
      // FIXME: no upstream branch is set -> no tracking information for the current branch
      // await git(cachePath).removeRemote('origin');
      // await git(cachePath).addRemote('origin', gitURL);
      // go into file and replace tocken
      // FIXME: fatal branch 'master' doesn't exist
      // execSync('git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master');
      // await git(cachePath).branch(['--set-upstream-to=origin/master', 'master'], (err, data) => {
      //   if (err) throw new Error(err);
      // });

      // Show all branches
      // debug('SHOW ALL BRANCHES');
      // await git(cachePath).branch(['-a'], (err, data) => {
      //   if (err) throw new Error(err);
      // });

      /* CMDs
      -------------------------------------------------- */
      try {
        execSync(`cd ${cachePath}`, { stdio: 'inherit' });
        execSync('git remote -v', { stdio: 'inherit' });
        execSync('git remote remove origin', { stdio: 'inherit' });
        execSync(`git remote add origin ${gitURL}`, { stdio: 'inherit' });
        execSync('git remote -v', { stdio: 'inherit' });
        // execSync('git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master', { stdio: 'inherit' });
        git(cachePath).branch(['-u', 'origin/master'], (err, data) => {
          if (err) throw new Error(err);
          console.log(data);
        });
        execSync('cd /home/ystanev/menlolab/runner', { stdio: 'inherit' });
      } catch (e) {
        throw new Error(e);
      }
      /* End of CMDs
      -------------------------------------------------- */

      debug('GIT PULL');
      await git(cachePath)
        .outputHandler(outputHandler)
        .pull();
```

The previous operation seems to unset upstream branch tracking, leaving me unable to `git fetch/pull`. Following the git output I've set tracking by executing `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master`, the issue seems to be fixed.

I've tried to do the entire thing though the `bash` commands, I keep receiving error:

`error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/master' does not exist`

There seem to be trouble with communication with remote repo, as the same commands run just fine from `bash` shell in local repo.

Any advice as to possible cause?

Comment: The `<upstream>` argument to `--set-upstream-to=<upstream>` must exist at the time you execute it. So after adding the name `origin`, you'll want to run a `git fetch origin` first, so as to create all the `origin/*` names, *then* do the `git branch --set-upstream-to` step.

Comment: @torek Thank you, that fixed me issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @torek in the comments, I had to run `git fetch` before setting the upstream.

The final code is bellow:

```
if (fs.existsSync(cachePath)) {
      debug(`Local Path ${cachePath} Exists`);

      // Fetch
      await git(cachePath).removeRemote('origin');
      await git(cachePath).addRemote('origin', gitURL);
      await git(cachePath).fetch('origin');
      await git(cachePath).branch(['-u', 'origin/master']);

      debug('GIT PULL');
      await git(cachePath)
        .outputHandler(outputHandler)
        .pull();
    }
```